# Async method as an expression in ternary expression

Tags: node.js, async-await, conditional-operator

I'm trying to call an async method inside a ternary expression as a condition, yet the execution of the code isn't working as expected.
Could someone explain to me why this :

```
req.user.user_id === concept.owner_id
  ? async () => {
      console.log("here");
      const update = req.body;
      update.concept_id = conceptId;
      update.owner_id = concept.owner_id;
      const updatedConcept = await Concept.updateConcept(update);
      updatedConcept !== null
        ? ResponseSuccess.success(res, updatedConcept)
        : ResponseError.internalServerError(res);
    }
  : ResponseError.unauthorized(res);
```

Isn't working?
I verified that the condition is true. FYI `ResponseSuccess` and `ResponseError` are just response handlers and formatters.
Is it because both parts are different types?

TIA

Comment: I don't see you calling that `async` function anywhere. So what I see is a ternary expression would evaluate to a function definition when the condition is true.

Comment: Yep, just noticed it. Thanks @crashmstr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the async function, you are just assigning it.

```js
req.user.user_id === concept.owner_id
  ? (async () => {
      console.log("here");
      const update = req.body;
      update.concept_id = conceptId;
      update.owner_id = concept.owner_id;
      const updatedConcept = await Concept.updateConcept(update);
      updatedConcept !== null
        ? ResponseSuccess.success(res, updatedConcept)
        : ResponseError.internalServerError(res);
    })()                                              // Do this to call it
  : ResponseError.unauthorized(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually executing your function on the true side of the ternary operator. You'll need something like this

```
  await (req.user.user_id === concept.owner_id
    ? async () { ... }
    : async () {
      return ResponseError.unauthorized(res)
  )()
```

But I would highly recommend you just use an if statement for this.

Comment: Why the preference for the "if statement" instead of the ternary expression?

Comment: It's much easier to read an if statement than an inline function inside a ternary operator. Also you won't have to wrap the false section in another inline function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use IIFE in order to call a function on declaration. Please refer the following link for more information regarding IIFE.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

The answer quoted by @zishone is based on **IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)**